# Nest Camera Stream / Dropcam to OpenCV

Tags: opencv, nest-api, embedded-flashplayer

I was wondering if there is a way to use the web_url function available from the nest camera, which returns an embedded flash video of the camera stream, to download the video into a buffer, from which I could do any analytics upon with OpenCV, e.g. face detection.

I don't know if saving the video from the embedded flash into a buffer is the way to go (how would I do this?); or if there's some way to access the stream from openCV as you can do with typical IP cameras?

Answer (score 0):

web_url simply gives the URL to the page on home.nest.com. The user has to be logged in. Nest Cam is not an IP camera and streams are not currently available via the API. You would need to write something to scrape the web page at home.nest.com that would be able to stay logged in.